# putting json into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json

I want to put a JSON object into a javascript variable as a sting in order to create a graph.

```
qm.createGraphData = function() {
$.post("ajax_getGraphDataWebsite    ", function(json) {
           qm.negativesData = json;
    },"json");  

    qm.data = [{
        "xScale":"ordinal",
        "comp":[],
        "main":[{
            "className":".main.l1",
            qm.negativesData},{
            "className":".main.l2",
            qm.negativesData}],
        "type":"line-dotted",
        "yScale":"linear"}];
}
```

the string value should be added to the "data" section. Now the object get's added but I need to add the string value to the variable like the sample below:

```
{"data":[{"x":"3283581","y":"2013-10-16"},{"x":"1512116","y":"2013-10-17"},{"x":"3967","y":"2013-10-18"},{"x":"1094","y":"2013-10-19"},{"x":"853","y":"2013-10-20"},{"x":"1205","y":"2013-10-21"},{"x":"2618700","y":"2013-10-22"},{"x":"3928291","y":"2013-10-23"},{"x":"3670318","y":"2013-10-24"},{"x":"3347369","y":"2013-10-25"},{"x":"2525573","y":"2013-10-26"},{"x":"3224612","y":"2013-10-27"},{"x":"3992964","y":"2013-10-28"},{"x":"3949904","y":"2013-10-29"},{"x":"3568618","y":"2013-10-30"},{"x":"3104696","y":"2013-10-31"},{"x":"3246932","y":"2013-11-01"},{"x":"2817758","y":"2013-11-02"},{"x":"3198856","y":"2013-11-03"},{"x":"3952957","y":"2013-11-04"},{"x":"3934173","y":"2013-11-05"},{"x":"3878718","y":"2013-11-06"},{"x":"3642822","y":"2013-11-07"},{"x":"3186096","y":"2013-11-08"}]}
```

This would generate the right graph for me. Does anyone know how to convert the json object into a string like above and to send it to the qm.negativesData variable?

**// UPDATE**

Now I've got the string with the qm.negativesData = JSON.stringify(json); solution

But my qm.negativesdata won't get added to the qm.data variable... i'm getting a console error SyntaxError: invalid property id

I suppose i'm not adding them the right way?

Comment: You're overthinking it man.

"JSON" JavaScript Object Notation.  You can literally assign the object to a variable.

Comment: If you have an object, `myObj` and you want it as JSON (a string) then you use `JSON.stringify(myObj)`. You haven't shown your source object in the question. You've got a `qm.data` object that doesn't seem to have any relationship with your desired output JSON string. Note that [there's no such thing as a JSON object.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @nnnnnn json is my source object? or you mean data which I juse in my PHP json encode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a JSON object into a JSON string, you can try `myObject.stringify()`, `JSON.stringify(myObject)`, or if you are using a library using the built in function of that library.

So, you could do something like: `qm.negativesData = myObject.stringify()`

Cheers

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a built-in `$.JSON` does it? Is that from a plugin?

Comment: it has worked with the myObject.stinify() option :) thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help :)  You could help me out, as well, by accepting my answer :D

Comment: @nnnnnn: You are corret. jQuery only contains $.parseJSON() natively, to parse a JSON string to an object. Nice catch, I have edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @mastahb: Are you trying to access it as `qm.data[i].main[j].negativesData` ? That would be the appropriate syntax, using i as the outer index and j as the inner index (your objects are wrapped in arrays).